# See submitted data in {{ userModel | json}} But unable to get data

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular7, angular-forms

I want see submitted data in  {{ userModel | json}}
But unable to get data.

I am using angular 7.0

Below is my Code. Please check and tell me where i'm getting wrong.

your help much appreciated

User.ts (Model)

```
export class User {
    constructor(
        public name: string,
        public email: string,
        public phone: number,
        public examselect: string,
        public perfencetocall: string,
        public promotional: boolean
    ) {}
}
```

app.component.ts

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    import { User } from "./user";

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })
    export class AppComponent {


      title = 'demo';
      userModel = new User ('vipin','rob@test.com',132456700555555,'morning','sdf',true)

    }
```

contact.component.html

```
 <div class="container">
        <h2 class=""> Contact form</h2>
        <br>
        <form #userForm="ngForm">
     {{ userForm.value | json}}
     <hr>
     {{ userModel | json}}
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-1" for="name">Name:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-11">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter email" name="name" [(ngModel)]="userModel.name">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-1" for="email">Email:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-11">          
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter password" name="email" [(ngModel)]="userModel.email">
            </div>
          </div>
  <div class="form-group">        
            <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-11">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>&nbsp;
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Reset</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
```

Comment: As far as I read, I didn't see anything you are doing to send the data to the server. For example: What happens on submitting the form?

Comment: i want to display data in this as JSON   {{ userModel | json}}

Answer (score 0):

*userModel* defined in your app.component.ts is not directly accessible to other components. To make it happen you can use techniques like - [component-interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction).

You can add below in your app.component.html

```
<app-contact [userModel]="userModel"></app-contact>
```

and in contact.component.ts file add`@Input() userModel: User;`